# Исключения при работе с итераторами

Tags: c++, c++11

Решаю следующую задачу: есть некоторый файл, структура которого представляет собой набор блоков. Каждый блок имеет заголовок и тело. Последний блок отмечен соответствующим идентификатором. Для обхода блоков в файле пишу собственный итератор:

```
/**
 * @brief Single-pass input iterator.
 */
class BlockIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, const DataBlock> {
  private:
    friend class FileReader;

    FileReader* reader;

    // Текущий блок, на который указывает итератор.
    std::unique_ptr<DataBlock> block;

    BlockIterator(FileReader* r, std::unique_ptr<DataBlock> b) noexcept : reader(r), block(std::move(b)) {
        /*NOP*/
    };

  public:
    BlockIterator& operator++() {
        auto nextBlockOffset = block->offset + block->headerSize + block->bodySize;
        block = reader->getBlockAt(nextBlockOffset);
        //              ^^^ Функция может выкидывать исключение!
        return *this;
    }

    BlockIterator operator++(int) {
        auto retval = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return retval;
    }

    bool operator==(const BlockIterator& other) const {
        return reader == other.reader && block == other.block;
    }

    bool operator!=(const BlockIterator& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }

    reference operator*() const {
        return *block;
    }
};
```

При инкременте функция `getBlockAt()` может выкидывать исключение (например, если парсим невалидный файл). Как в этом случае лучше поступать: необходимо ли гарантировать отсутствие исключений при работе с итератором? Если да, то как обеспечить инвалидацию итератора и вывод ошибки?

Comment: Может добавать в ваш итератор метод isValidBlock или типа того, чтобы его проверяли перед использованием. Или если получили исключение переходить к следующему блоку, но тогда про ошибку внешняя программа не узнает.

Comment: Моё ИМХО. Поскольку Вы наследуетесь от `std::iterator`, то нужно следовать его идеологии. Итератор предполагает валидность при указании на существующие данные, а неправильные данные (невалидный файл) есть для итератора исключительная ситуация. А исключительная ситуация должна выбрасывать исключение. Частично моё мнение подтверждается тем, что итераторы стандартной библиотеки не объявлены как не генерирующие исключений.

Comment: @Unick Переходить к следующему блоку не имеет смысла, если ошибка, то можно заканчивать работу с файлом. По дополнительной функции для проверки валидности можно подумать, но возникает дополнительный overhead, поэтому хотел узнать как обычно поступают в таких случаях.

Comment: @kff, спасибо, тоже склонялся к такому мнению.

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку есть наследование от std::iterator<...>, то имеет смысл сохранять его идеологию обработки подобных ошибок.

Согласно [последнему опубликованному черновику стандарта С++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf), нужно кидать исключение:

> Results of most expressions are undefined for singular values; the
>   only exceptions are destroying an iterator that holds a singular value...

Стр. 856, п. 7

Answer (score 0):

Игнорировать ошибку нельзя, нужно как-то о ней сообщить всегда. Как сообщать зависит от того где вы используете этот итератор, если только в своём коде тогда можно либо метод сделать для проверки ошибочности текущего значения итератора (в этом случае при разыменовании итератора ошибочного нужно обязательно исключение бросать, либо итератор перемещать на end() сразу чтобы обработка завершалась), если вы хотите использовать итератор со стандартной библиотекой типа STL, тогда в идеологии итератора нет возможности вернуть ошибку кроме как через исключение, тогда нужно бросать исключение, но его будет ловить уже не STL код а тот кто им выше пользуется. Если исключения бросать никак нельзя вам по какой-то причине, тогда нужно просто итератор при перемещении на невалидный блок сразу смещать в конец end() либо пытаться пропустить один блок если такое можно сделать и найти как-то следующий блок например по специальному уникальному набору байт в начале заголовка, тогда программа обработки посчитает что обработка полностью завершена, хотя будут не обработанные блоки, это не приведёт к краху программы, просто данные не будут все обработаны, такое поведение часто бывает у обработчиков разных данных, они если не могут сообщить об ошибке тогда пытаются пропускать битые данные и сохранять где-то информацию об ошибках в статистике или логе внутри своих структур, тогда потом можно после работы узнать сколько битых блоков было пропущено и были ли вообще ошибки.